# number of rows dynamic in codeigniter pagination links

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I am working on Codeigniter (Gocart) Project.I am stuck on one task,I need your help.

I want to show option to select number of records per page.By default controller index action is as follows

```
function index($order_by="id", $sort_order="DESC", $code=0, $page=0, $rows=15)
```

and I am having dropdown in views for number of rows.

then in controller I have written a condition.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['num_rows'])){
            $rows   =   $_REQUEST['num_rows'];
        }
        else{
            $rows   =   $rows;
        }
```

and this is the codeigniter pagination code of controller.

```
$this->load->library('pagination');


        $config['base_url']         = site_url($this->config->item('admin_folder').'/products/index/'.$order_by.'/'.$sort_order.'/'.$code);
        $config['total_rows']       = $data['total'];
        $config['per_page']         = $rows;
        $config['uri_segment']      = 7;
        $config['first_link']       = 'First';
        $config['first_tag_open']   = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close']  = '</li>';
        $config['last_link']        = 'Last';
        $config['last_tag_open']    = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close']   = '</li>';

        $config['full_tag_open']    = '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
        $config['full_tag_close']   = '</ul></div>';
        $config['cur_tag_open']     = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close']    = '</a></li>';

        $config['num_tag_open']     = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close']    = '</li>';

        $config['prev_link']        = '&laquo;';
        $config['prev_tag_open']    = '<li>';
        $config['prev_tag_close']   = '</li>';

        $config['next_link']        = '&raquo;';
        $config['next_tag_open']    = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close']   = '</li>';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

and in view

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();?>
```

Now how will I set number of rows to dynamic for paginate links.I hope you got my question

Answer (score 0):

First of all, This should do the trick:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['num_rows'])){
        $rows   =   $_REQUEST['num_rows'];
}
```

Else condition isn't really required here as you are assigning $rows to itself.

Other than this, CodeIgniter purges the $_REQUEST variable for security reasons. So I believe IF condition is always false. Unless you have set 'global_xss_filtering' variable to true in config file.

You can also use `$this->input->get('num_rows')` or `$this->input->post('num_rows')` depending on which method you are using.

Everything else seems OK to me.

Comment: no this can not work.Please read my question.At first time it will work as we can pass page values via form but when we click on pagination link how to resend that value.As we are using just <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();?>

Comment: @BhuvneshGupta, You can set `$config['page_query_string']` to true. It will change segments to query string and `per_page` will added in it automatically. OR if you want to keep segments, simply add `$rows` in base url as you are adding others. Pagination links are based on base url. Both of these methods are explained [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html)